# Add single or multiple items to a list

Tags: c#, list, polymorphism

I have this class:

```
public class Itemcollection : Item
{
    public List<Item> Items{ get; set; }
}
```

And now I add the item(s) to a List

```
if (item is Itemcollection collection)
{
   list.AddRange(collection.items);
}
else
{
    list.Add(item);
}
```

Is there way to avoid the object check (if (item is Itemcollection collection)) and do this on a more generic way or somthing similar.

Comment: Sure: by not storing different things (single items and collections) into your list. In other words: by not inheriting `Item` in your `ItemColelction`.

Comment: Are you sure you need the Itemcollection class? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt

Comment: _"Is there way to avoid the object check"_ - what's the problem with the current code?

Comment: @SᴇM this "if is .." can be avoided very easily here and that's exactly what op wants.

Comment: @Joelius What OP wants and why is different things, is that giving him an error or unexpected results or something?

Comment: Why your `ItemCollection` class inherits from (a single) `Item`? That's confusing. It's like if an `University` inherits from a `Student`.

Comment: @SᴇM I don't think this throws any errors it's just bad in general because the parameter would have to be of type object which usually seems to me like a design flaw. Or actually in this case it could be of type Item because of the weird inheritance scheme op has but still this pattern should usually be avoided.

Comment: @TimSchmelter It's a recursive structure in which each item can contain more collections.  It's used for modeling tree structures.

Comment: If you insist on this structure, you could add a virtual add(IList) method to item and override in itemcollection

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends what type is object *item*, but I think you can not do it without type check. You can wrap your code in a method and do that check there. Another option is method overloading.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having certain items that have an `Items` collection, and some that don't, ensure that *all* of your items have a collection of items in them.  Then simply have that collection contain a single item if the object logically represents a single value rather than a collection of values.  That way in  your code here (and elsewhere) where you process an item you can process *all* of the items, and if "all of the items" ends up being one item, so be it.